# Reference types

Tags: .net

```
 var a = MyClassInstance;
    MyClassInstance = null;
    //if (a !=null){ //why }
```

I think that `a` points to `MyClassInstance` and `MyClassInstance` equals null, then `a` must be equals null too. But `a` is not null and I don't understand why.

Comment: I dont think thats the correct way to "nuillify" a class. You might have to call an internal destroy fucntion. You are setting something in the class to NULL but the actaull class still exists and is not Null...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `a` is a reference, so the value it holds is the "location" of some object. `MyClassInstance` is also a reference. By setting `a = MyClassInstance` they both point to the same instance. Setting `MyClassInstance` to null affects that reference only. It doesn't affect the object itself and it doesn't affect any other references.

Answer (score 5):

`a` and `MyClassInstance` are references to an object.
Changing one reference doesn't change the other.

```
var a = MyClassInstance; // Both references point to the same object
MyClassInstance = null;  // MyClassInstance now points to null, a is not affected
```

Comment: a and MyClassInstance are references to an object? Not to area of memory?

Comment: At the end of the day this is the same.

Comment: @Alex the fact that references are implemented as pointers is an implementation detail http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Because you are assigning `null` to the variable `MyClassInstance` which just *referenced* your actual instance located on the heap. You do not touch your actual class instance in any way.

In fact, you cannot directly free the memory your class instance occupies; this is what the garbage collector is for. It looks if there are any *references* (think pointers, but not) to your instance left, and if none remain, the object is deleted/collected from memory.

Maybe this makes it clearer: http://en.csharp-online.net/Value_vs_Reference

Answer (score 2):

The variable of a reference type instance is mainly a pointer to a memory address - so your example is comparable to

```
int MyClassInstance = 0x1234; // points to a memory containing *your* values
int i = MyClassInstance;
MyClassInstance = 0x0;
if (i !=0x0){ //still 0x1234, because it's a copy }
```

Or in other words:
the variable is the reference, not the object itself. So the second variable is a copy of the reference.

Comment: But it's value types, not references!

Comment: Yes, and as the name says: a reference type. So what you get when you create a variable from a reference type is a **reference**. And a reference for itself is a special value type to address the memory. Depending on your CPU, it's either a 32 or a 64bit value.